# Loading images faster in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, image-processing, httphandler

I have a gridview which displays data for all employees and their images (stored in database).
The images take more time to render completely when i click sort or paging or reload.
I'm using httphandler to display image as stream. 
Is there a way i can speed up this image loading?

Comment: If they are static images and don't change, embed them your project as resources, and call them.

Comment: You could add cache to the httphandler so the images are cached by the browser so you don't need to re-retrieve them every time you sort, etc.

Comment: how will this httphandler caching work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the byte arrays in `HttpContext.Current.Cache` and return them from the cache in the `IHttpHandler`.